# Access Permissions for Live Chat Replies and Omni-Channel Request Visibility

Tags: security, omnichannel, digital-engagement

I have successfully configured the Live Chat script and can view incoming message conversations.  However, the Reply button functionality is currently disabled.  To resolve this, I would like to inquire about the specific permissions required to enable live chat message replies.

[image]

Additionally, within the Omni-Channel console, my submitted requests are not displaying.  I would appreciate clarification on any additional permissions or licenses necessary to ensure proper visibility of my requests within the system.

[image]